# Navigate to scene and not have back show up

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux, native-base

I am building an avatar builder, and I am having some issues with my implementation of react-native-router-flux. In the example below, I am having the user land on the "home". They access the race scene which would then send them to the subrace scene. My issue is when I am done selecting a subrace, I send them back home using Actions.home. It brings them home, but also has the back button enabled. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Scene key= 'root'>
            <Scene key= "home" hidenavbar={true} component={HomeScreen} title="Create Character" initial={true} />
            <Scene key= "race" component={Race} title="Choose Race"  />
            <Scene key= "subrace" component={Subrace} title="Choose Subrace" />
          </Scene>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

below is the subrace component

```
export default class Subrace extends Component {

   render(){
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header><Title>Choose Subrace</Title></Header>
        <Content>
          <List>
            <ListItem button onPress = {Actions.home}>
              <Thumbnail square size={80}/>
              <Text>Underground elf</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem button onPress = {Actions.home}>
              <Thumbnail  square size={80} />
              <Text>forest elf</Text>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also try 

```import { Router, Scene, ActionConst} from 'react-native-router-flux';

<Scene key= "home" hidenavbar={true} component={HomeScreen} title="Create Character" initial={true} type={ActionConst.RESET}/>```

Comment: just use `type={'reset'}` in your `<Scene key='home'/>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
export default class Subrace extends Component {

   render(){
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header><Title>Choose Subrace</Title></Header>
        <Content>
          <List>
            <ListItem button onPress={() => Actions.home({ type: 'reset' })}>
              <Thumbnail square size={80}/>
              <Text>Underground elf</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem button onPress={() => Actions.home({ type: 'reset' })}>
              <Thumbnail  square size={80} />
              <Text>forest elf</Text>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```